# I Can't get my bash code right to check an answer read in

Tags: string, bash, shell, compare

My current script is like this but is for one answer.

```
A1="hp"
 echo
 echo 1.What os uses swinstall for software installs?
 read answer
 if [ "$answer == "$A1" ]; then
         echo "correct"
 else
         echo "incorrect"
 fi
```

(for questions with two answers)i would like to put in place of this see below i would like for them to be able to choose either answer up top though.
echo the answer could be hp or ux

Comment: You missed the title, it might be *you* who doesn't get the `bash` code right;)

Comment: sorry it did not post the way i wrote it .

Comment: And there's at least one additional or missing double-quote in the if. Pro tip: you can see the preview of your post below the edit box:)

Comment: Seems like you have an extra "

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `if [ "$answer" = "$A1" ]; then`

Comment: how could i maybe do A1="hp" and A2="ux" with A3="A1,A2"   would that work?

Comment: That second `echo` should have quotation marks; `?` is a wildcard. And you should tell us what the problem is; you've only told us that it's not right, not how it fails.

Comment: how could i maybe do A1="hp" and A2="ux" A3="A1 or A2" does anyone know how i could make this happen or point me in right direction to find it please i cant seem to find it

Answer (score 0):

What about using a case statement? This allows for a bit of flexibility:

```
A1="hp"
A2="ux"
echo
echo 1. What OS uses swinstall for software installs?
read answer
case $answer in
($A1)    echo "correct"
         ;;
($A2)    echo "correct"
         ;;
(*)      echo "incorrect"
         ;;
esac
```